# DIY Multispectral camera Rededge

Tags: remote-sensing, hyperspectral-sensor

I am trying to build my own multispectral camera using a Raspberry Pi, RGB camera, and Near IR Camera. My original goal was to measure the NDVI index. However I am now interested in the NDCI index as well, measuring chlorophyll. I was wondering if there was a way to get the Red Edge from these two cameras. The central wavelength of 705 nm?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83672/can-raspberry-pi-noir-camera-see-near-infrared-light-1550nm